# What is a good name for the premise in the rule for implication introduction?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

I have the following standard inference rule:

```
Rule (ImplicationIntroduction)
  Premise
    [P]...Q
  Conclusion
    P=>Q
```

I'm putting together the BNF to parse this and I have:

```
 metastatement                ::=   subproof

                                |   metavariable

                                ;



 subproof                     ::=   supposition "..." metastatement ;

 supposition                  ::=   "[" metastatement "]" ;
```

The `metaVariable` rule is given elsewhere, by the way, in the [BNF](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/occam-proof-assistant/Parsers/master/es6/florence/bnf.js) that puts this snippet in context.

Here I've copied [Stanford](http://logic.stanford.edu/intrologic/glossary/implication_introduction.html) and called the premise `subproof` but I don't particularly like it. 
Something with 'derivation' in it, perhaps.

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: If you like 'derivation' ... then why not 'subproof'?  And I think subproof is fairly standard nomenclature.

Comment: It's good to hear that 'subproof' is fairly standard. Do you know of any references aside from Stanford?

Comment: OK, I went through my collection of books .. I probably overstated that 'subproof' is 'fairly standard'  (probably worked with the Stanford systems too much myself!) .. I am finding a few other books that use 'subproof', (e.g. 'Introduction to Logic by Pospesel' and 'Elements of Deductive INference' by Bessie and Glenman),  but I also found 'subordinate proof' ('The Art and Science of Logic' by Bonavec), and (you'll like this!) 'subderivation' ('The Logic Book', Bergman, Moor, and Nelson).

Comment: Ha! I think you've put more effort into this than the question deserves. I'm going to stick with subproof. I like it a bit more now I've dropped the capital p (although the spelling checker likes it less).

Comment: I'm not overly keen on derivation because I don't think derivations, especially subderivations, should necessarily start with suppositions (by the way I prefer 'supposition' to 'assumption' and it irks me that few people seem to appreciate the difference).

Comment: What about [hypothetical proof](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=iJrpCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA259&dq=hypothetical+proof&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiwtYXSitzUAhWGL1AKHUwcCM8Q6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=hypothetical%20proof&f=false)?

Comment: There is [conditional derivation](http://www.oswego.edu/~delancey/111_DIR/CIL6.pdf). I'll stop now.

Comment: Hmm, the 'hypothetical proof' seems to be used a bit differently, and the 'conditional derivation' is really used for the whole process of conditional proof ... and I note they do use 'subproof' there as well to refer to the structure used in conditional proof/derivation.

Comment: You're right about the use of conditional derivation. So [subproof](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/occam-proof-assistant/Parsers/master/es6/florence/defaultCustomGrammar/metastatement.js) it is. If you want to post an answer I can accept it and we're done.

Comment: Alright! Good luck with your project!

Comment: Thanks! Custom grammars are beginning to make it come alive...

Comment: Conditional In, or Introduction In.

Comment: Hi, Doug. I was looking for a name only for the premise, not the rule as a whole, by thanks anyway.

Comment: "Conditional proof" seems straightforward enough.  Btw, most natural deduction proofs, while displayed for humans in a fitch style, are actually recorded on computers in lambda calculus due to the curry howard isomorphism.  That is one of the major appeals of natural deduction.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Daniel. I went with subproof in the end.